# Representing different level of interface in an app

Tags: interface, labels

I have one app which populate interface based on the choice of user. User has exactly three options to choose level of features/complexity/difficulty. My question is what would be the best approach to show those levels

**OPTION 1**

1. LEVEL 1
2. LEVEL 2
3. LEVEL 3

**OPTION 2**

1. BEGINNER/NOVICE
2. INTERMEDIATE
3. ADVANCE

In my understanding, option 1 is quite confusing because it doesn't give any information about what would be the next level. Also, if there are level1,level2,level3 then user would expect there could be more levels whereas in option 2 those two problems gets solved.

Is there any better approach than this? Also, which one would be more preferable from UX stand point?

My application is certainly not a gaming application but a communication app. I have seen option 1 a lot in mobile games which has multiple levels where they have more than three levels.

P.S. For labels I am mostly going to use TEXT based labels.

Comment: What does the level of features actually equate to? Is it the type of options that uses can select/access, or the layout of the interface or a combination of different things? If so then the labelling isn't so much progressive as it is just variations of user preference. There's no need to label it to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @MichaelLai, Let me explain this  -  these interface show different layout and different set of features. Labeling is IMPORTANT because it give user some idea about what s/he could expect from that particular selection. All these interfaces don't have different features but different sets for example - advance level will have all the features whereas beginner will only have basic features.

Answer (score 4):

Most mobile games have more than 3 levels, and only numbers fit the need of naming them. But level equals not to mode. Even some games contain easy, normal and hard modes. I guess they are more like to be **mode** in your app? So words that clearly indicate the differences between them should be better, and that's option 2. As English is not my native language, I can only suggest some related words like standard/primary/junior, normal/intermediate，advanced/senior/master :)

Comment: Same thought and thanks for alternative words for levels. Much appreciated. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Levels (1-2-3) imply progression and skill development. Level language is common in games, educational software, and fitness software where the user progresses as they use the software.

Named tiers imply different levels of user assistance or control. Tiered interfaces are common in vehicle settings, device settings, and software people use for professional work. Some examples:

- Cars offer driers eco/comfort/sport modes
- Turbo Tax offers guided/manual modes
- Cura 3D printing software offers recommended/custom modes
- Wireless routers offer basic/advanced configuration interfaces
- The Excel ribbon has a default set of controls but can be customized

If a tiered interface is appropriate for your software, it is important to talk with people who will use it to choose appropriate text labels for each tier. At best, an inappropriate tier name will confuse users by making it difficult to recognize and access the desired tier. At worst, the tier name may offend your users. For example, an expert may be offended by a “beginner” tier but appreciate a “recommended” tier. Make sure to test the names you give the tiers before shipping your product.

Comment: @Good point about not offending users with labels.

Answer (score 2):

This seems more like a semantics issue, which will require that you combine the benefits of asking your potential users and considering space to fit each word.

Here are a few suggestions. Note they are self explanatory, which is the best route; I don't need to tell you what each mode will deliver.

I also think you should have only 2 options, as the differences between the middle option and those adjacent to it are likely to be mild or cause confusion when it comes to select the interface.

- Basic, compact, clean, simple
- Full, complete, detailed, standard

Comment: english ins't our primary language so it would be good idea if you can provide a list of words which we can use.  :) And thanks for your reply: )